# Python dictionary printing specific value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this variable with two dictionaries in it:

```
dic = {"id": 2125, "role": "Policy", "visible": "Users", "name": "Peering", "phone": "", "email": "peering@fb.com"}, {"id": 2568, "role": "NOC", "visible": "Users", "name": "Network Operations", "phone": "+1 650 308 7200", "email": "noc@fb.com"}
```

I want to print de e-mail addresses which belongs to 'role' NOC!!

I can use

```
for key in dic:
    if key['role']=='NOC':
       print(key['email'])
```

But I don't want to use if key['role']=='NOC': . Anyone a better idea? to print email address which belongs to a specific role.

Comment: **But I don't want to use if key['role']=='NOC'** Any specific reason?

Comment: because then i have to do it for each role

Comment: @EteqEteq, That's true. But how can you possibly **avoid** performing the test on each `key['role']`? However you market it, a loop is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this simple case, you can create a dictionary with the keys being the roles themselves:

```
> roles = {d['role']:d for d in dic}
> roles['NOC']['email']
```

Note that you are still looping through all dictionary items to create the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(dic))
email = df.loc[df['role'] == 'NOC', 'email']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make any sense, but to reach to your value without your aforementioned line of code, write:

```
for eachDict in dic:
    lst = eachDict.values()
    if 'NOC' in lst:
        print eachDict['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

```
for entry in filter(lambda x: x['role'] == 'NOC', dic):
    print(entry['email'])
```

The comparison ist still there, but your `if` statement is gone.